# jQuery, 1 line removeClass not working

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

to start with I have this:

```
<body class="nojs">
```

I'm trying to remove the "nojs" class and replace with "js", so I can set CSS fallbacks properly. This is the code I'm using:

```
<script>$("body").removeClass("nojs").addClass("js");</script>
```

I'm connected to jQuery as other plugins are working fine, however this just won't work. Irrespective of whether I put it in the head or body tag.

Does anyone know what's wrong? Still does not work when in a (document).ready function.

Comment: It works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/AgUxj/

Comment: Intriguing. Could you shed some light as to why it might not be working here? On the most simple of test pages?
http://christianbullock.com/75438438744/test.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>testing remove class</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="nojs">
        <script>$("body").removeClass("nojs").addClass("js");</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As suggested above. If you don't use onReady then the DOM might not be ready in time for you to carry out your change.

Comment: Extraordinary, cannot put finger on why mine wasn't working. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('nojs').addClass('js');
});
```

Are you getting any script errors?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsfiddle to show this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/k47dZ/

Basically, if you have this:

```
<div id="m">
    <div id="a" class="nojs"></div>
</div>
```

and then do this:

```
alert($("#m").html()) 
$("#a").removeClass("nojs").addClass("js");
alert($("#m").html())
```

it works as expected. Can you try embedding the above example into your project and confirming it works?